# dat GUI doesn't change my values

Tags: javascript, dat.gui, particles.js

I have an object called alt.

```
  alt = ('particles-js',
{
  "particles": {
    "number": {
      "value": 80,
      "density": {
        "enable": true,
        "value_area": 800
      }
    },
  }
);
```

I want to control the number "value" with a slider, which I have managed to create below.

```
var gui = new dat.gui.GUI();


gui.add(alt.particles.number, 'value').min(1).max(800).step(1);
```

Which creates a user interface that accurately picks up that the value is 80.

If I increase 80 manually, there's an obvious increase in the number of particles.

In addition if I call

```
alt.particles.number.value = 500
```

There is also a change in the number of particles.

However, when I change the slider, pictured here: https://imgur.com/a/72XXY

Nothing changes. Any ideas how I can get this slider to change this value live?

Comment: What is that syntax you're using to declare `alt`? Does not look like Javascript to me. Definitely that syntax with the `('', {})` does not represent a Javascript object.

Comment: I don't actually know, as it's not my code. That's why I was confused. I'm basically trying to achieve a similar affect to what is here: https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/#default